# How to pass the i-ith value of an array to scipy.integrate using dopri5 (runge-kutta45)?

Tags: python, scipy, parameter-passing, differential-equations

I am trying to use **sci.integrate python module** to solve for V (the voltage on a capacitor) a simple first order in time ODE:

```
def f(t, V, Vin, vtime, R):
    return (Vin[vtime==t][0]-V)/(R*get_alpha(V))

R = .5
V0 = 0.
t0, dt, tmax = vtime[0], vtime[1]-vtime[0], vtime[-1]
result, time = np.zeros_like(V), vtime

r = ode(f).set_integrator('dopri5')
r.set_initial_value(V0, t0).set_f_params(V, vtime, R)

i = 0

while (r.successful()) & (r.t < tmax):
    result[i] = r.integrate(r.t+dt)[0]
    i+=1
```

As you can see my right-hand-side functional depends on an input voltage (stored in an array *Vin*) and a constant resistance (*R*), both of which I would need to pass to the function within the solver as an argument at each time.

The example given on the scipy documentation page is not clear enough to me as I am not able to simply call r.set_f_params(Vin, R).

**What is the proper way to set those parameters?**

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement some interpolation formula for `Vin`. In the most simple case,

```
def getVin(t): k = int( (t-t0Vin)/dtVin ); return Vin[k];
```

where of course you have to provide the paramters `t0Vin, dtVin` of the sampling times of the `Vin` samples.

For more general situations use the interpolation function `numpy.interp` or `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`.

Comment: If I integrate at each point of Vin, interpolation is not needed. I am concerned with passing this array (then extracting the proper value given the time step) or the single voltage value at that time step to the function within the rk4 method. Sorry if the question wasn't clear enough in the first place.

Comment: Yoiu are working under a misconception. `scipy.integrate.ode` does not use RK4 and does not use a fixed step. You have no guarantee on what times the derivatives function is called and that they are in chronological order. Most popular higher order methods jump back-and-forth. You can of course re-start the integration every time the `Vin` value changes. Thus should be a full restart, wth resetting the initial point along with the parameters.

Comment: In the link below, it is explicitly said that integrate.ode implements the runge-kutta method of order (4)5

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html#scipy.integrate.ode

Comment: Yes, also called the Dormand-Price method. Which is an order 5 method with an embedded order 5 method (or vice versa). Not the classical RK4. And it uses an adaptable internal step size with interpolation of the values that are returned in the `integrate` method.

Comment: I see what you mean. This wasn't directly the answer I was looking for but turned out to be very helpful. I will thus vote your reply up, thank you!

Comment: In fact... I programmed the 'classical' rk4 and it is giving the same results as Dormant-Price, so I guess I was either lucky or indeed using it properly. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Parameters other than the time and function itself can be set by **r.set_initial_value(V0, t0).set_f_params(V, vtime, R)** but their names in the function have to be *arg1, arg2, etc...*